# Error when starting beeline because of Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hiv e/conf/HiveConf

Tags: hive, beeline

I'm working on windows8, I have installed hadoop and hive successfully. hiveserver2 is running in 10002. hive also.
But when i try to connect to beeline by entring this command :
beeline !connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/ i have this error

```
 Fichier introuvable
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hiv
e/conf/HiveConf
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544
)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveCon
f
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 7 more
```

i can't fix the source of the error.
i'm working with mysql.

Comment: The Hadoop stack is really, really not designed to run on Windows. `JNI error` and `Fichier introuvable` (file not found) suggest that a DLL was not found in the PATH (which is where Java searches for DLL on Windows when they are not in its "library path" property). Any warning about _native libraries_ ?

Comment: Did you get fix for it, because i am currently facing exact same error?